If you said you ate on top of the tower, it seems as though
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/on-top-of-vs-on-the-top-of.2180289/
In post #3, in the above thread, they say:

If you said you ate on top of the tower, it seems as though you sat literally on the roof. On top of it.

By "if you said", are they talking about a hypothetical situation (=if you were to say), OR are they talking about a real situation (=if you said in the past)?

It is poor grammar. But it's not a scholarly article, it's just a comment on a forum. There's no point analysing things like this.

Yeah: "If you said you ate on top of the tower, it would seem as though you sat literally on the roof. On top of it." would be more correct, but is a bit too fussy for conversational situations. Or you could put it all in the present tense but that might require going back and editing the first part, which is too much work.

@StuartF, you say "you could put it all in the present tense". What would it look like in the present tense? Could you please write it here for me?

Note, this is one of those "mistakes" that is so common that it isn't really a "mistake" except in formal writing. Substituting past tense for hypotheticals is very common in informal use. I learned the difference when I was corrected for mis-singing the Fiddler on the Roof number as "If I Was a Rich Man."

It could be either. It is formally ambiguous.
The were to say form avoids the ambiguity; but people often say things which are formally ambiguouse, confident that their audience will understand what is meant.

Just one more question, sir. Supposing that sentence (1) in question was hypothetical (ie, If you were to say you ate on top of the tower, it would seem as though you sat literally on the roof. On top of it). What would be its corresponding "real tense" version? This one: if you say you eat on top of the tower, it seems as though you sit literally on the roof? OR this one: if you say you ate on top of the tower, it seems as though you sat literally on the roof? I hope I'm not bothering you (-:
